# how to compile Rmarkdown file only until the error

Tags: compilation, r-markdown, rendering

This is about rendering a Rmarkdown file containing errors.

I am aware that you can configure a Rmarkdown document with *error=TRUE* to keep compiling although an error is present, and it generates your html or pdf file.

However, I would like to find a way in which the compiling process stops in the error, and the posterior chunks are not run, but it still generates the html or pdf file from the output of the previous chunks.

Does someone know how to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: dot dot dot a year later... add this to your options `knitr::knit_hooks$set(error = knitr::knit_exit)` and make sure you still have `knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE)` as well